# Animation, AngularJS: Animation speed in pixels per second?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have two lines of text one on top of the other. Content of each line is dynamic.

Is there a way to set animation speed in pixels per second? So that line would scroll with same speed regardless of their length?

Example of the situation:

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#line1 {
    background-color: green;
}

#line2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    /* Animation delay 0.5s */
    -moz-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
}

#line1 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 200%;
}

#line2 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 600%;
}

@keyframes line-scroll {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="line1">
    <h4>I don't want to come off as arrogant here, but I'm the greatest botanist on this planet.</h4>
</div>

<div id="line2">
    <h4>Every human being has a basic instinct: to help each other out. If a hiker gets lost in the mountains, people will coordinate a search. If a train crashes, people will line up to give blood. If an earthquake levels a city, people all over the world will send emergency supplies. This is so fundamentally human that it's found in every culture without exception. Yes, there are assholes who just don't care, but they're massively outnumbered by the people who do. ~ Mark Watney, The Martian</h4>
</div>
```

Means of `AngularJS directive` and `CSS` are welcome.

Comment: I have found the solution using JQuery. You can check the same. I think it solves your problem.

Comment: @geeksal: looks good.

Comment: thank you! if you think that it solves your problem than please mark it as accepted

Comment: Sure - need some time to test it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery (javascript) to get the width of headings and than calculate the duration based on the width i.e duration per pixel

`width()` method of jquery is used to get width of the headings.

I calculate the the duration as follows:

```
1s = 20px

Therefore 100px = 100/20
                = 5s
```

You can increase the denominator (see the number`10`)   in `var dur1=Math.ceil(w1/10)` to speed up the scrolling.
Here is the code

```js
//getting the width of both the headings
var w1=$("#line1>h4").width();
var w2=$("#line2>h4").width();

//calculating the duration of the animation dynamically based on the width
var dur1=Math.ceil(w1/10);
var dur2=Math.ceil(w2/10);

//setting the duration dynamically
$("#line1>h4").css("animation-duration",dur1+"s");
$("#line2>h4").css("animation-duration",dur2+"s");
```

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#line1 {
    background-color: green;
}

#line2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    /* Animation delay 0.5s */
    -moz-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
}

#line1 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 200%;
}

#line2 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 600%;
}

@keyframes line-scroll {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line1">
    <h4>I don't want to come off as arrogant here, but I'm the greatest botanist on this planet.</h4>
</div>

<div id="line2">
    <h4>Every human being has a basic instinct: to help each other out. If a hiker gets lost in the mountains, people will coordinate a search. If a train crashes, people will line up to give blood. If an earthquake levels a city, people all over the world will send emergency supplies. This is so fundamentally human that it's found in every culture without exception. Yes, there are assholes who just don't care, but they're massively outnumbered by the people who do. ~ Mark Watney, The Martian</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you must provide the animation duration in [time units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/time), which is currently seconds / miliseconds.

You could, however, adapt the width of the transition by switching from a %-value to px-values like shown below:

```css
div {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#line1 {
    background-color: green;
}

#line2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

h4 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    /* Animation delay 0.5s */
    -moz-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
    animation: line-scroll 15s linear 0.5s infinite;
}

#line1 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 200%;
}

#line2 h4 {
    /* width must be big enought to fit in whole text othrwise
    whole text will not scroll into view */
    width: 600%;
}

@keyframes line-scroll {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-1000px);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="line1">
    <h4>I don't want to come off as arrogant here, but I'm the greatest botanist on this planet.</h4>
</div>

<div id="line2">
    <h4>Every human being has a basic instinct: to help each other out. If a hiker gets lost in the mountains, people will coordinate a search. If a train crashes, people will line up to give blood. If an earthquake levels a city, people all over the world will send emergency supplies. This is so fundamentally human that it's found in every culture without exception. Yes, there are assholes who just don't care, but they're massively outnumbered by the people who do. ~ Mark Watney, The Martian</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Disadvantage of this solution is that the line with much shorter text is empty for quite some time before animation resets after its content scrolled away.